# How to encrypt and decrypt a string using AWS KMS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I am trying to use AWS KMS to encrypt and decrypt a simple string,
I am using the AWS Javascript SDK to do so,
I am able to encrypt and somewhat decrypt the string as there are no errors,
But the output of the KMS decrypt method, does not result in my original string which I was trying to encrypt.

**Here is my working code -**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');

AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
var kms = new AWS.KMS({apiVersion: '2014-11-01'});

let test = async () => {

    try {
        let data = `test`;

        var encryptionParams = {
            KeyId: "someKMSKeyId",
            Plaintext: data
        };

        let kmsEncrypt = util.promisify(kms.encrypt).bind(kms);
        let encryptedData = await kmsEncrypt(encryptionParams);

        //encryptedData contained 2 parts, CiphertextBlob and KeyId
        console.log('encryptedData => \n', encryptedData);
        console.log('\nencryptedData.CiphertextBlob => \n', encryptedData.CiphertextBlob);
        console.log('\nencryptedData.KeyId => \n', encryptedData.KeyId);

        var decryptionParams = {
            CiphertextBlob : encryptedData.CiphertextBlob
        };

        let kmsDecrypt = util.promisify(kms.decrypt).bind(kms);
        let decryptedData = await kmsDecrypt(decryptionParams);

        //ndecryptedData contained 2 parts, Plaintext and KeyId
        console.log('\ndecryptedData => \n', decryptedData);
        console.log('\ndecryptedData.Plaintext => \n', decryptedData.Plaintext);
        console.log('\ndecryptedData.KeyId => \n', decryptedData.KeyId);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('\nerror => \n',error);
    }
}

test();
```

I am expecting the output of `decryptedData.Plaintext`to be **test**,
But the output is something like - `<Buffer 74 65 73 74>`,
What am I doing wrong here?

**Reference -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/KMS.html#endpoint-property

Comment: The output from `decrypt` is Base64 encoded. Not sure how you decode that in JavaScript, so not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to kdgregory's hint, I was able to resolve this by decoding the PlainText into a String using `base64`,
**Following is the final working code for encryption and decryption using AWS KMS -**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');

AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
var kms = new AWS.KMS({apiVersion: '2014-11-01'});

let test = async () => {

    try {
        let data = 'test';

        var encryptionParams = {
            KeyId: "kmsKeyId",
            Plaintext: data
        };

        let kmsEncrypt = util.promisify(kms.encrypt).bind(kms);
        let encryptedData = await kmsEncrypt(encryptionParams);

        //encryptedData contained 2 parts, CiphertextBlob and KeyId
        console.log('encryptedData => \n', encryptedData);
        console.log('\nencryptedData.CiphertextBlob => \n', encryptedData.CiphertextBlob);
        console.log('\nencryptedData.KeyId => \n', encryptedData.KeyId);

        let buff = Buffer.from(encryptedData.CiphertextBlob);
        let encryptedBase64data = buff.toString('base64');
        console.log("\nencryptedBase64data => \n", encryptedBase64data);

        var decryptionParams = {
            CiphertextBlob : encryptedData.CiphertextBlob
        };

        let kmsDecrypt = util.promisify(kms.decrypt).bind(kms);
        let decryptedData = await kmsDecrypt(decryptionParams);

        //ndecryptedData contained 2 parts, Plaintext and KeyId
        console.log('\ndecryptedData => \n', decryptedData);
        console.log('\ndecryptedData.Plaintext => \n', decryptedData.Plaintext);
        console.log('\ndecryptedData.KeyId => \n', decryptedData.KeyId);

        let buff2 = Buffer.from(decryptedData.Plaintext, 'base64');  
        let originalText = buff2.toString('ascii');
        console.log('\noriginalText => \n', originalText);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('\nerror => \n',error);
    }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement your answer.

> **Plaintext**
>
> Decrypted plaintext data. **When you use the HTTP API or the
>   AWS CLI, the value is Base64-encoded**. Otherwise, it is not encoded.
>
> Type: Base64-encoded binary data object
>
> Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 4096.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_Decrypt.html#API_Decrypt_ResponseElements